# Recall `input` with a while loop if an incorrect answer is supplied

Tags: python, loops, input, while-loop, continue

Python doesn't return to the enclosing loop when I use `continue`, due to a mistake I can't catch.

The following loop should prompt the user for two generic names I set up: `George` and `David`. I want to have it set up so Anaconda asks the user for their name. If they enter `George`, it says `Hi George`. If they enter `David`, it says `Hi David`.

If the user enters any other name, it calls back the loop to try again. I am still a beginner at Python and my knowledge of control flow here shows.

I know that `continue` works only with a `while` conditional. My code was written such that: else, while the name is not `George` or `David`, trigger `continue`, which should go to the enclosing loop (if the name is not `David` or `George`, ask for the name again).

```
name = ''
if name != 'David' and name != 'George':
    print('What is your name?')
    name  = input()
    if name == 'David':
        print('Hi David')
    elif name == 'George':
        print('Hi George')
    else:
        while name != 'George' or 'David' :
            continue
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `while` and `if` mixed up. There are actually multiple ways to solve this:

```
name = ''
while True:
    print('What is your name?')
    name = input()
    if name == 'David':
        print('Hi David')
        break
    if name == 'George':
        print('Hi George')
        break
```

Or

```
name = ''
while name != 'David' and name != 'George':
    print('What is your name?')
    name = input()
if name == 'David':
    print('Hi David')
elif name == 'George':
    print('Hi George')
```

Or even better, you could use `in` to check if `name` is an element in the `set` of all accepted names. For the `print` call, you don't have to explicitly write `David` and `George` again, but you can use the new variable `name`:

```
name = ''
while name not in {'David', 'George'}:
    print('What is your name?')
    name = input()
print('Hi {}'.format(name))
```

Comment: `while name not in ['David', 'George']` A set lookup would be better, no?

Answer (score 0):

```
while True:
    print('what is your name?')
    name  = input()
    if name == 'David':
        print('hi david')
        break
    elif name == 'George':
        print('hi george')
        break
```

You do not need a `continue` in this code. A `continue` is typically used to skip intensive steps that do not need to run further provided certain conditions are fulfilled.
For example:

```
while True:
    x = float(input('Enter a number: '))
    if x > 1023: 
        print (f'{x} is too large to compute') 
        #OverflowError: (34, 'Result too large')
        continue
    print (2**x) #Max: 2**1023
    break
```

Comment: @Jayjayyy I actually saw your comment like 1 second after I edited it because I received a downvote and looked through my code 1 more time to check and noticed the weird while loop. Thanks though :)

Comment: @Jayjayyy Thanks, do you have a good example code for `continue` skipping steps? I included one but I feel its not the best at demonstrating `continue`